# Error while starting WAS while WXS (Websphere Extreme scale) is integrated in WAS

Tags: websphere, ibm-wxs

Hi I have integrated WXS (Websphere eXtreme Scale server) in WAS network deployment. After that i created Catalog service domain in System Administration in WAS admin console.

[image]

And also set following custom property under System Administration > Cell: catalog.services.cluster 10Cell01\10Node01\nodeagent:10.91.9.59:2500

[image]

Where 10Cell01 is cellname, 10Node01 is node name and nodeagent is my nodeagent, 2500 is the client port that is given while creating Catalog service domain. I synched the changes and restarted nodeagent and JVM and while starting nodeagent i am getting following exception:

> "[6/23/16 17:32:20:588 IST] 00000001 FfdcProvider W
>   com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident
>   emitted on
>   /was/IBM/WAS8.5/inst1/profiles/Appsrv01/logs/ffdc/nodeagent_c047c374_16.06.23_17.32.20.5842431899872602750460.txt
>   null 1011 [6/23/16 17:32:20:590 IST] 00000001 ContainerHelp E
>   WSVR0501E: Error creating component
>   com.ibm.ws.objectgrid.integration.ObjectGridCatalogComponentImpl
>   java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   com.ibm.ws.objectgrid.integration.ObjectGridCatalogComponentImpl.getHostName(ObjectGridCatalogComponentImpl.java:682)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.objectgrid.integration.ObjectGridCatalogComponentImpl.initialize(ObjectGridCatalogComponentImpl.java:318)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerHelper.initWsComponent(ContainerHelper.java:1192)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerHelper.initializeComponent(ContainerHelper.java:1099)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerHelper.initializeComponents(ContainerHelper.java:901)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.initializeComponents(ContainerImpl.java:776)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.initializeComponents(ContainerImpl.java:750)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ServerImpl.initialize(ServerImpl.java:333)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.bootServerContainer(WsServerImpl.java:336)
>   at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.start(WsServerImpl.java:267) at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.main(WsServerImpl.java:730) at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServer.main(WsServer.java:59) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611) at
>   com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.launchMain(WSLauncher.java:234) at
>   com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:95) at
>   com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.run(WSLauncher.java:76) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611) at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethodWithException(EclipseAppContainer.java:587)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:198)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611) at
>   org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:340) at
>   org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:282) at
>   org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:981) at
>   com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.launchEclipse(WSPreLauncher.java:376)
>   at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.main(WSPreLauncher.java:147)

Also this one after that:

> srv01/logs/ffdc/nodeagent_c047c374_16.06.23_17.32.21.660333321497041948629.txt
>   null 789 [6/23/16 17:32:21:661 IST] 00000001 WsServerImpl W WSVR0100W:
>   An error occurred initializing, nodeagent [class
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ServerImpl]
>   com.ibm.ws.exception.ConfigurationWarning: Exception caught when
>   initializing component at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerHelper.initWsComponent(ContainerHelper.java:1237)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerHelper.initializeComponent(ContainerHelper.java:1099)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerHelper.initializeComponents(ContainerHelper.java:901)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.initializeComponents(ContainerImpl.java:776)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.initializeComponents(ContainerImpl.java:750)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ServerImpl.initialize(ServerImpl.java:333)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.bootServerContainer(WsServerImpl.java:336)
>   at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.start(WsServerImpl.java:267) at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.main(WsServerImpl.java:730) at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServer.main(WsServer.java:59) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611) at
>   com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.launchMain(WSLauncher.java:234) at
>   com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:95) at
>   com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.run(WSLauncher.java:76) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611) at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethodWithException(EclipseAppContainer.java:587)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:198)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611) at
>   org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:340) at
>   org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:282) at
>   org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:981) at
>   com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.launchEclipse(WSPreLauncher.java:376)
>   at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.main(WSPreLauncher.java:147)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   com.ibm.ws.objectgrid.integration.ObjectGridCatalogComponentImpl.getHostName(ObjectGridCatalogComponentImpl.java:682)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.objectgrid.integration.ObjectGridCatalogComponentImpl.initialize(ObjectGridCatalogComponentImpl.java:318)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerHelper.initWsComponent(ContainerHelper.java:1192)
>   ... 35 more"

WAS Version: 8.5
WXS Version: 8.6

Comment: You mention you are using WXS Version: 8.6.  Are you using 8.6.0.0 or 8.6.0.8?  It looks like you are using an older version that is two and a half years ago, can you try 8.6.0.8?  Thanks

Comment: Hi @Abelard Chow, I was using 8.6.0.0. But now i updated my WXS to 8.6.0.8. Still problem persist. Exception coming in Admin console while doing test connection:

    The connection attempt to the catalog service domain failed. Verify that the catalog service is running. The following exception caused this error to occur: [com.ibm.websphere.objectgrid.ObjectGridRuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: port out of range:-1]

Comment: You are getting a " java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: port out of range:-1".  It looks like you haven't specified a port and the default -1 is being used.

Comment: @Abelard Hi, Can you please tell me which port i need to define? I have specified client port for catalog server, also defined the Bootstrap port that is 2809.

Comment: Based on the screen shot, I think you need to specify the Listener Port.  It should be the port used by catalog server, which is 2809.  Please let me know how it goes.  Thanks